# Scheduling large numbers of events in Mysql

Tags: mysql, scheduling

Looking at using the Mysql event scheduler to schedule potentially quite a large number of events which could be in the 100,000's of discrete events per day (possibly more). Does anyone have any experience with scheduling such volumes of events in mysql and if they encountered any pitfalls or issues with implementing things this way.

Comment: That is odd. Why do you need so many?

Comment: The application itself more or less would allow customers to schedule micro tasks which could potentially scale to a large volume of scheduled events.  I guess thats the real problem that needs to be solved and thought it might be ok to do direct at the source in the database